# How to convert Google short URLs back to its original URL?

Tags: php, short-url

I have some short URLs. How can I get the original URLs from them?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the URL-shortener-services are mostly simple redirectors they use the [location header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_location) to tell the browser where to go to.

You can use PHP's own [`get_headers()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.get-headers.php) function to get the appropriate header:

```
$headers = get_headers('http://shorten.ed/fbsfS' , true);
echo $headers['Location'];
```

Comment: thank you @patrik-mayer . it's working for all Ow.ly , Bit.ly , goo.gl , tinyurl.

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you should check for the HTTP-Response to be sure that there is a 301 Location. It is common, that your browser gets redirected more than once. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php 

$url="http://goo.gl/fbsfS";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$a = curl_exec($ch); // $a will contain all headers

$url = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); // This is what you need, it will return you the last effective URL

echo $url; // Redirected url
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`curl` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) for this:

```
// The short url to expand
$url = 'http://goo.gl/fbsfS';

// Prepare a request for the given URL
$curl = curl_init($url);

// Set the needed options:
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => TRUE,            // Don't ask for a body, we only need the headers
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => FALSE,   // Don't follow the 'Location:' header, if any
));

// Send the request (you should check the returned value for errors)
curl_exec($curl);

// Get information about the 'Location:' header (if any)
$location = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);

// This should print:
//    http://translate.google.com.ar/translate?hl=es&sl=en&u=http://goo.gl/lw9sU
echo($location);
```

Comment: `curl -ILs -o /dev/null -w %{url_effective} http:// goo.gl/fbsfS $'\n'` seems to be much easier. If the service doesn't like HEAD instead of GET, omit the `-I` option from `curl`.

Comment: The question is about how to do this in PHP.

Comment: Now it see it. Since it's only in the label and neither in title nor in text, it's easy to miss if you just look this topic up in Google. Maybe it helps someone else who just google-searched for a general solution, so I leave the comment up.

Answer (score -1):

For all services there is an API, which you can use.

Comment: you're talking about the exact opposite of what he's asking

Comment: @NeilMartin: Of course not. With this APIs you can even get the original URLs

Comment: Then you need to be clear in your answer of what you're talking about. Moreover, he'l have to code differently for ever url shortener api in the entire internet. Think about the implementation. Is it feasible for what he needs?